error while file upload using nodejs (not express)
Help to find the temporary file path. during the file upload using Nodejs (no express)
I have tried to handle file uploads using Nodejs (no express). After parsing the uploaded file will be saved into a temporary file. but we need to rename it right? To rename that file, the old path and the new path is required.
How can i find old path?



A tip would be to paste the code here instead of sharing screenshots of it
